# What is the relation between a function with free variables and a closure?

Tags: scala, haskell, closures, lambda-calculus

Are free variable(s) in a function the thing(s) "closed" upon in a closure?

Comment: If you are using definition of combinator from CS, you should use a definition of closure from CS - and in CS "closure" is not a function, it is an environment in which function was created, which binds some values to function's variables. So, unless you would define the environment to "miss" some values, I would say that the only variables without set values in closures are arguments. Therefore I wouldn't call it "an opposite", more like orthogonal things.

Comment: Disagree with this. Closure = function + environment (or "control part" and "environment part"). So a combinator is a subset of closure where the environment is empty.

Comment: @Tim it depends how you interpret "Joel Moses credits Landin with introducing the term closure to refer to a lambda expression whose open bindings (free variables) have been closed by (or bound in) the lexical environment, resulting in a closed expression, or closure". I understand it that you take a function with free variables, and then use environment to bind values to each of these variables making them bounded variables. Therefore closure would create a combinator out of function with free variables.

Comment: Free variables are just that: *free*. They don't have any known binding. A closure contains one or more variables that are bound in a non-local, but still known, scope.

Comment: whether a variable is free or bound depends on the code fragment to which we focus out attention. `x` in `(\x. \y. (x+y))` is bound, precisely because `x` in `\y. (x+y)` is free. is `x` bound in `(\x. y)`? doesn't look like it, for that lambda term is equivalent to `(\w. y)` and there's no `x` in `(\w. y)` at all. as to "closure" it starts from a lambda term with free variables in it (if there's no free vars in it, then there's no problem). the question arises, how are those vars to be understood / interpreted? if we do nothing special and just keep this term-with-free-vars as is, (contd.)

Comment: then we hope that at the time it is reduced / applied, those vars are somehow defined. this is then the _dynamic binding_ discipline, a source of many errors in early Lisps. instead, we can form a _pairing_ of this term-w-f-v and the environment in which it is created. and that pairing is a _closure_. aka ["funarg device"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+funarg) of Moses. used to _emulate_ lexical scoping in dynamic Lisps. and if a language has immutable variables, we can just substitute the values of those vars directly into the term, so there's no need for "closure", again.

Comment: we only need the pairing with the actual environment if those bindings are mutable, and accessible from several points, so that a change in one must be observable from the other.

Comment: so, "combinator" i.e. lambda term with no free vars, does not need any pairing to have its free vars' bindings capped -- it has no free vars to begin with. (re bindings "capped" ... it's like chemical valency thing. terms with free vars are like free radicals). that's all there is to it.

Comment: Short answer: "No".

Comment: @BenWeaver Instead of editing your question into a completely different question, you might rather want to [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Depends on the language. In Haskell, there are no free variables, period. Those would be unbound variables, and the code would not compile.